# Thread safe version ObservableProperty in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, thread-safety

I have the following class in my application:

```
class SomeService {

    @Volatile
    var property: String? = null

    fun loadProperty() {
        // this code loads property value from external source
    }

}
```

- There is only one instance of `SomeService` within the application
- `loadProperty` is executed from a single thread on a given schedule
- Other threads of the application may reach `someService.property`
- `@Volatile` ensures thread-safety

Now I need to add some post-processing of the fact that the value is changed.
Kotlin provides the following structure to do this:

```
var property: String? by Delegates.observable(null) { _, _, newValue ->
    println(newValue)
}
```

However this structure is not thread safe while adding `@Volatile` is not allowed.
Is there any ready-to-use Kotlin structure that represents thread safe observable?
Or writing my own version of `ObservableProperty` class that supports thread safety is the only option?

Comment: Do you ever set `property` outside of `loadProperty()`? If not then I think you don't really need the observable property - simply put your post-processing to `loadProperty()`. Observable property is good if we don't control who/where changes the value of the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After applying the [translation of delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#translation-rules-for-delegated-properties), you'll notice that there is no longer any properties in your class that `@Volatile` can be added to.

```
private val property$delegate =
    object : ObservableProperty<String?>(null) {
        override fun afterChange(property: KProperty<*>, oldValue: T, newValue: T) = ...
    }

var property: String?
    get() = property$delegate.getValue(this, this::property)
    set(value: String?) = property$delegate.setValue(this, this::property, value)
```

`@Volatile` cannot go on `property$delegate` because it never actually changes, and it can't go on `property` because it no longer has a backing field.

This basically means you need to make your own `ObservableProperty`. What actually needs to be `@Volatile` is this `value` property in `ObservableProperty` ([source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/05896a42da04620a2e8ca35e952ff31c3c48aa9d/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/properties/ObservableProperty.kt#L14)):

```
public abstract class ObservableProperty<V>(initialValue: V) : ReadWriteProperty<Any?, V> {
    // this needs to be volatile
    private var value = initialValue
```

Now knowing that, it is easy to write your own volatile version:

```
inline fun <V> Delegates.volatileObservable(initialValue: V, crossinline onChange: (property: KProperty<*>, oldValue: V, newValue: V) -> Unit) =
    object: ObservableVolatileProperty<V>(initialValue) {
        override fun afterChange(property: KProperty<*>, oldValue: V, newValue: V) =
            onChange(property, oldValue, newValue)
    }

abstract class ObservableVolatileProperty<V>(initialValue: V) : ReadWriteProperty<Any?, V> {
    @Volatile
    private var value = initialValue

    protected open fun afterChange(property: KProperty<*>, oldValue: V, newValue: V) {}

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>) = value

    // @Synchronized is needed if you are setting it from multiple threads
    @Synchronized
    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: V) {
        val oldValue = this.value
        this.value = value
        afterChange(property, oldValue, value)
    }
}
```